# Change size of armature bones?

Tags: 3d-view, armature, bones

I want to be able to do is change the size of the big bone a bit so I can actually see what I'm animating.

I want to be able to wireframe the armature so I can see the hands.

So in other words, I want to be able to see the fingers, making the whole armature a lot thinner but not bigger or longer, and the then be able to see through it.

[image: Big Bone over sized?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it see-through, you can change the armature's *Maximum draw type* to *Wire* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

You may also want to disable *X-ray* in the same panel so the armature is not displayed when it it is behind or inside other geometry:

[image]

Comment: I think OP might be after xray rather than wire and that wasn't the question either.

Comment: @iKlsR The OP said "I want to be able to wireframe the armature so I can see the hands", so I thought I would mention it.

Comment: YES^ Thank you very much! you really helped me alot today

Answer (score 13):

To adjust the size of the *B-Bone* display type in Blender, enter *Edit* mode and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. It will scale while keeping it constrained. To scale on a specific axis, select the desired axis after triggering this with <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: I'm trying to change the display size of the B-Bone but when I do ctrl+alt+S it shows up the save menu

Comment: @Tak Need to be in edit mode.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options available to alter the display of an armature. [See the manual for more detail](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Visualization)

One option that reduces the visible size of the armature is to use Stick display, this is available in the Armature display options.

[image]

Which makes the armature look like this -

[image]

You can also use any mesh object in place of a single bone to make each part of the armature unique. You also have the option of displaying these objects as wireframe only.

[image]

This last option is very common, an example is the hand rig generated by the metarig addon which gives you this appearance for a hand -

[image]

Comment: Whoa thats a long ( and great ) answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry but the correct answer was givin before you! very sorry but i will thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

To scale B-bones, you need to press the key combination:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>